Error: Page "/[...path]" is missing "generateStaticParams()" so it cannot be used with "output: export" config
The problem is that the error is not telling the truth. The function generateStaticParams exists!!
I've made this file:
/** ./app/[...path]/page.tsx */
import React from "react";

export function generateStaticParams() {
  return [];
}

export default function Page() {
  return <>path</>;
}

When I build using yarn next build... after a while I see Error: Page "/[...path]" is missing "generateStaticParams()" so it cannot be used with "output: export" config. in console and build fails.
